# How I can create a shortcut to maximize/minimize windows in Lubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu, shortcut-keys, window

In `lubuntu-rc.xml` Lubuntu doesn't have a hotkey to maximize the current window.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here are some keybindings I use for window control on Lubuntu/LXDE. The first binding is what you're searching for but I thought you might find the other ones useful as well:

```
<!-- Keybindings for window tiling -->

    <keybind key="C-W-Up">        # FullScreen
      <action name="Maximize"/>
    </keybind>
    <keybind key="C-W-Down">        # MiddleScreen
      <action name="UnmaximizeFull"/>
      <action name="MoveResizeTo"><x>center</x><y>center</y><width>50%</width><height>50%</height></action>
    </keybind>

    <keybind key="C-W-Left">        # HalfLeftScreen
      <action name="UnmaximizeFull"/>
      <action name="MoveResizeTo"><x>0</x><y>0</y><height>100%</height><width>50%</width></action>
    </keybind>
    <keybind key="C-W-Right">        # HalfRightScreen
      <action name="UnmaximizeFull"/>
      <action name="MoveResizeTo"><x>-0</x><y>0</y><height>100%</height><width>50%</width></action>
    </keybind>

    <keybind key="C-W-1">        # UpperQuarterLeft
      <action name="UnmaximizeFull"/>
      <action name="MoveResizeTo"><x>0</x><y>0</y><height>50%</height><width>50%</width></action>
    </keybind>

    <keybind key="C-W-2">        # LowerQuarterLeft
      <action name="UnmaximizeFull"/>
      <action name="MoveResizeTo"><x>0</x><y>-0</y><height>50%</height><width>50%</width></action>
    </keybind>

    <keybind key="C-W-3">        # LowerQuarterRight
      <action name="UnmaximizeFull"/>
      <action name="MoveResizeTo"><x>-0</x><y>-0</y><height>50%</height><width>50%</width></action>
    </keybind>

    <keybind key="C-W-4">        # UpperQuarterRight
      <action name="UnmaximizeFull"/>
      <action name="MoveResizeTo"><x>-0</x><y>0</y><height>50%</height><width>50%</width></action>
    </keybind>
```

You might have to tweak the percentages based on whether you use a panel or not.

`C-W-Up` means <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SUPER</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd>

Comment: When I push `CTRL` + `ALT` + `T` - started LXTerminal. How I can make all new opening windows in Lubuntu in default open in full size (not F11)?

Comment: I insert your code to my `lubuntu-rc.xml` before last tag `</openbox_config>` - after restart this hotkeys not working.

Comment: You will have to insert these bindings somewhere between the `<keyboard> </keyboard>` tags. `</openbox_config>` marks the end of the configuration file. Please see [here](http://urukrama.wordpress.com/openbox-guide/#Key_mouse) and [here](http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Bindings#Key_bindings) for more information.

Comment: As for starting all new windows of a specific application in a maximized state, you can find out more about this [here](http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Applications).

Comment: You made my day! Your hotkeys and OBApps work great!

Comment: Happy to hear that! Enjoy customizing Openbox, it really is fun ☺!

Comment: This worked fine for me, but in Lubuntu 22.04 the correct file to add the above configuration is: ~/.config/openbox/rc.xml

Answer (score 4):

For completeness of this thread, I'm going to collate some information from elsewhere.

To edit the config file:

```
gedit ~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml
```

To apply the changes:

```
openbox --reconfigure
```

And personally, I want windows key (or super key) + up to toggle maximization and W+down to minimize (or iconify), so I personally change

```
<keybind key="W-Up">         # HalfUpperScreen
  <action name="UnmaximizeFull"/>
  <action name="MoveResizeTo"><x>0</x><y>0</y><width>100%</width><height>50%</height></action>
</keybind>
<keybind key="W-Down">       # HalfLowerScreen
  <action name="UnmaximizeFull"/>
  <action name="MoveResizeTo"><x>0</x><y>-0</y><width>100%</width><height>50%</height></action>
</keybind>
```

to

```
<keybind key="W-Up">        # Maximize
  <action name="ToggleMaximize"/>
</keybind>
<keybind key="W-Down">      # Minimize
  <action name="Iconify"/>
</keybind>
```

Comment: `<action name="ToggleMaximize"/>` does not work on `lxqt-rc.xml`, but `halfupper` and `halflowerscreen` work.

Answer (score 2):

To open **all** applications maximized (not full screen as with `F11`), place the following code between `<applications>` and `</applications>` in `lubuntu-rc.xml`:

```
<application type="normal">
  <maximized>true</maximized>
</application>
```

<sup>This code is already present, but is commented out along with a lot of other useful options, in the `applications` section of `lubuntu-rc.xml`.</sup>