# Lubuntu maximize current window hotkey

Tags: lubuntu, shortcut-keys

Is there a keyboard shortcut for maximizing the current window on Lubuntu 16.04?

Comment: Your answer can be found at https://askubuntu.com/questions/305767/how-i-can-create-shortcut-for-maximize-minimize-window-in-lubuntu?rq=1

Comment: Alt+spacebar followed by `x` for maximize!